# latex, documentstyle book, how page numbers always bottom centered?

Tags: latex

I am writing a 100+ page thesis using latex, with the document style "book".

Right now the page number is bottom centered on the first page of a chapter, on the top outer margin on the subsequent pages of a chapter.

I want the page numbers to always be bottom centered on each page, for roman as well as arabic page numbers. How I can I do this?

Comment: if you haven't done too much with the book class yet, you might want to take a look at `memoir` -- it's quite good.

Answer (score 14):

Use `\pagestyle{plain}` in the header, and read this section of the [LaTeX Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) on Wikibooks for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look on the fancyheader [package](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/).

You will probably have to do something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\begin{document}
Your content \ldots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the page style can also affect the defaults. For example setting the page style to `\pagestyle{empty}`
will also remove both header and footer information, such as the page numbers in the footer.

The apporach with fancyhdr as mentioned is the way to directly modify these. Another way to clear the header and footer information with that package is `\fancyhf{}`.

The free online LaTeX wikibook is an excelent resource, here is the link for the page layout page which covers issues such as headers nad footers.

[LaTeX Wikibook - Page Layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout)

Hope that helps,

Jay